# Assert most recent parameter passed to registered callback function is correct with Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, controlvalueaccessor

In Angular's [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface, the following method is defined:

```js
registerOnChange(fn: any): void;
```

When testing a component that implements `ControlValueAccessor`, I need to assert that the most recent parameter value passed to the `fn` which is passed to `registerOnChange` is the expected value. Note that I'm not asserting the value for `fn` itself, but the parameter value that is passed to the `fn` which is passed to `registerOnChange`.

How might I do this?

I was trying something along these lines, but it did not seem to work. The test "passes" in cases where I would expect it to fail.

```js
...
scenarioArray.forEach((scenario) => {
  it(`changing control value should return correct date value`, fakeAsync(() => {
    // arrange
    component.writeValue(scenario.writtenControlValue);

    // act
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
      input.value = scenario.newControlValue;
      input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

      // TODO (below not working): assert expectedResult is passed to fn passed to registerOnChange
      spyOn(component, 'registerOnChange').and.callFake((arg: moment.Moment) => {
        expect(arg.toISOString()).toEqual(
          scenario.expectedResult.toISOString()
        );
      });
    });
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[callFake](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/SpyStrategy.html#callFake) is used when you would like to call fake method when invoked. That being said it is supposed to be located before the method is being invoked.

Jasmine has a matcher called [toHaveBeenCalledWith()](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/matchers.html#toHaveBeenCalledWith) so you can verify `registerOnChange` argument.

```js
  it(`changing control value should return correct date value`, fakeAsync(() => {
    // arrange
    ...
    spyOn(component, 'registerOnChange')

    // act
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {

      ...

      expect(component.registerOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(scenario.expectedResult.toISOString());
    });
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the right direction, however I'm not asserting the value for `fn` itself, but the parameter value that is passed to the `fn` which is passed to `registerOnChange`. Two levels deep, essentially. Any ides on that?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the `mostRecent` helper from `jasmine`. [Jasmine doc](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction)

```js
spyOn(component, 'registerOnChange');
...
fixture.detectChanges();
...
expect(component.registerOnChange.calls.mostRecent()).toEqual();
```

Edit:
This may not be the cleanest of approaches but we can stringify the function call and then assert on the string.

```js
const mostRecent = component.registerOnChange.calls.mostRecent();
expect(mostRecent.toString()).toContain(/*...*/);
```

To stringify the function, check out the below snippet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the right direction, however I'm not asserting the value for `fn` itself, but the parameter value that is passed to the `fn` which is passed to `registerOnChange`. Two levels deep, essentially. Any ides on that?

Comment: I have made an edit. It may not be the cleanest but I think it could work.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that could work. Because the specific component I'm testing passes a `Moment` (complex object) to the `fn`, this could get real gnarly to perform the assertion on the stringified method call. I just posted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66228736/2343739) that _seems_ to work for me for now, but is still not ideal. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [AliF50's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66225608/2343739), I figured out a sub-optimal solution that *seems* to work for this case for now. Since I know the internal API of the component under test, I can `spyOn` the `private` member that stores the callback function (in this case, `onChange`).

This will break if the `private` `onChange` member is ever renamed or refactored, however, so it'd still be nice to have a test that tests the `public` `registerOnChange` instead.

```js
...
scenarioArray.forEach((scenario) => {
  it(`changing control value should return correct date value`, fakeAsync(() => {
    // arrange
    spyOn<any>(component, 'onChange'); // Answer: spyOn private member
    component.writeValue(scenario.writtenControlValue);

    // act
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
      input.value = scenario.newControlValue;
      input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

      // assert
      expect(component['onChange'].calls.mostRecent().args[0].toISOString()).toEqual(
        scenario.expectedResult.toISOString()
      );
    });
  }));
});
```